# Android Intent Filter for url

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, deep-linking

Below is my code, where

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.Profile"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="somename"
                android:pathPrefix="/league/user"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I want to avoid opening the activity when url contains proceed as param. Can anyone point me how to do this.

**EDIT**
Giving an example

1. somename/league/user?id=100
2. somename/league/user?id=100&proceed=4

So, i want to avoid the url pointed out in "2" when proceed as param, from opening the activity.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to ask. Please explain more.

Comment: @K.Sopheak, I have edited my question.